# Stop Writing File to TextBox C#

Tags: c#

I have some problem with writing file to TextBox in C#. Something what I want is when I press button, date and time will be written to textbox and automatically stop writing even though the button still be pressed. What should I do ? I can't stop writing file to TextBox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        countermerah1++;

        if (countermerah1 == 1)
        {
            StatusBox.Text += "B" + "\r\n";
            countermerah1 = 0;

        }

    }
```

Comment: You are setting countermerah1 back to 0 each time then incrementing it to 1 which makes your if statement true every time.

Comment: Thanks for replying, StephenBrickner but I still confused where is the part that I must change ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: there should be an option to flag for "does not belong on site, op should google "programming for absolute beginners""... :/

Comment: @Alfonsus Dhani - What sort of button control is this handler servicing? A standard Windows Forms Button control should only trigger the Click event once,  after the button is released.

Answer (score 0):

Would this meet your requirements?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StatusBox.Text += "B" + "\r\n";
    StatusBox.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: No, that is not. I mean when I push the button, file will be written to the TextBox continously on the new line. I just want to write once even though button still be pressed.